# Moving in steps or smoothly, changing the default settings

Tags: customization

By default when you are grabbing part of a mesh you can move it around smoothly or you can press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to move it in steps.

Somehow I pressed something I wasn't supposed to and now it moves in steps normally and I have to keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed to move selections around smoothly, how can I return to the default settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you have turned snapping on.

Holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key toggles on snapping temporarily. I presume you have accidentally turned snapping on, meaning the Ctrl key will now toggle snapping *off*.

You can turn it off my clicking the magnet icon in the 3D header toolbar:

[image]

(The image shows snapping is turned on)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! As I thought it was a trivial problem, but being a beginner I can't quite find things in all the toolbars...

Comment: Feel free to mark this question as 'Accepted' if you find this answers your question. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I couldn't accept it earlier for the time limit